# Cannot access c$ administrative share in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing

I have two machines at work running Windows 10.  From one, I can connect to the c$ administrative share, but trying to connect from the other to the first computer's c$ share fails.

I have read about the [workaround](https://tommynation.com/enable-remote-access-administrative-shares-windows-10/) for adding a registry key to enable access to administrative shares, but it seems hackish.  And the first computer whose admin share I can access has no such registry key.

Is there some Windows setting I am missing to enable access to administrative shares?

Comment: What you call a workaround, is not a workaround. It is the only solution. If the Registry key is absent, you have to create it. But also, it drastically diminishes security of the affected computer. Clearly, you've found the solution; you just don't like it.

Comment: @FleetCommand I agree.  I don't like it.  But it is not the only solution.  See the answer I submitted for my own question below.

Comment: LOL. See the comment I submitted for your answer.

Comment: Additional info on [my blog](https://www.talk-about-it.ca/cant-connect-admin-ipc-shares-computer/) as well - including installing the required services

Answer (score 7):

Are the 2 windows you have the same type? i.e. Home vs Professional? or something else?

Windows-10 C$ share usually comes disabled by default when UAC is ON. Disabling UAC would allow you that access, since UAC isn't something you should disable especially on Windows-10 due to breaking down of other functionality and app-store apps etc, the only way left is to enable the registry key using the command below on the windows that you are trying to connect into (running from a command/DOS window with "Administrator" rights):

1. Start -> type cmd (don't hit ENTER yet)
2. Right-click on the Command Prompt as it appears on the top, and then select "Run as Administrator"
3. Type in the following command:

   REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
4. (Optional): Restart Windows.

Should work fine after that.

I hope this helps

Comment: Actually you don't need to restart Windows, it affects the Windows (10 - not sure about earlier versions) immediately

Comment: Hi Noam, if you don't restart Windows the policy won't be re-loaded from the registry, if you like to keep windows without restarting then you need to (1) start Task Manager, (2) Goto "Details" (3) Find all "explorer" instances, kill them all (right click End-Task), (4) Use the menu to "new task" and the enter "Explorer" when prompted, it should re-load again, ... I don't recommend this approach (i.e. easier to restart Windows as it's quicker on Win10 than older versions), I hope helps.

Comment: Hi Heider - I tried it and no restart was needed, nor any of the end-task processes, on Windows 10 it works without a reboot

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Noam, I will note that down. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Thank you - this is what worked for me. And can confirm no reboot was required

Answer (score 6):

On the computer you are having trouble connecting *to*, search for the Windows setting for: **"Manage Advanced Sharing Settings"** and make sure that **"Turn on file and printer sharing"** is selected for your Domain network.

[image: Turn on file and printer sharing]

Doing this will automatically enable the necessary Windows firewall rules to enable file sharing and also ping/ICMP responses.

Or, if you like, you can enable the following firewall rules yourself, as shown below. These must be configured on the computer you want to access, not the computer attempting to gain access.
[image: Specific rules in Windows Advanced Firewall configuration]

Comment: Did you even try this yourself? It does not work.

Comment: @FleetCommand Yes. This worked for me in my environment. That is why I documented it here.  I thought it might be helpful to someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Try reproducing it on a pristine virtual machine then. You will discover that it does not work.

Comment: Well. I see this answer has received upvotes. (Not just the answer; also, the question, the answer and your comment.) That's odd, because this answer isn't just wrong; it is blatant nonsense. I can tell that because I know what Windows Firewall and Windows sharing settings do.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed. For some Windows 10 VMs in a domain environment I couldn't access the C$ share from another machine. The issue was only that I needed to go in and turn on file and printer sharing, as shown here

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and yet strangely I was able to access the IP address in this form

```
\\10.5.0.33\c$
```

Whereas

```
\\computername\c$
```

still doesn't work.

I can't say its a dns issue as ping -a works fine. So if you do hit this problem accessing via the ip address might be a useful workaround for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can make this answer work, if you expand the next section "All Networks" and check the option for "Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the Public folders"
user477799: Disclaimer; This works in my environment on more than 1 machine with different subnets.