# access denied when mapping c$ from another computer

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders

I am sure this is very common problem, but somehow I cannot google the solution quickly enough, so I ask here :)
I have two Windows 10 PCs. From PC1 I can do net use \pc2\c$, authenticate as administrator and it is a success. From PC2 I cannot do it though and I get access denied - system error 5. Local administrator account is active and I tried runas to see if I type the proper password. I also created another user and added it to administrators group, but can't map the drive using this account either. In secpol.msc "access this computer from network" administrators is listed.
I can however map a non admin share which I have created on some folder there. So what else can it be?

Comment: Check Network Sharing, Advanced settings and make sure Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing and Password Protected sharing are all ON. Mapping to C$ was removed some time back. See if you have some old protocol like SMBv1 on one of the machines.

Comment: all of these is enabled...

Comment: You have SMBv1 running?  That has been deprecated and may not be on one of the computers. Microsoft is uninstalling SMBv1

Comment: all SMB 1.0 things are unchecked in "turn windows features on or off"

Comment: See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1218973/cannot-access-c-administrative-share-in-windows-10

Comment: @Vitas .... If these are workgroup and not domain computers, create a user account on both computers with the same username and the same password. Grant that account access to the `C$` share or grant it local admin, and then try to map the drive with `NET USE`. I'll be happy to write up a prettier answer for you if you tell me and confirm that that resolves the issue. Otherwise, you can try to make both those local administrator accounts on the two different computers have the same password and that should work. The username and password must match in my experience in workgroup configurations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One very common solution to the problem is to disable
[UAC remote restrictions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction):

- On PC1, run `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
- If an item named `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` doesn't exist,
  create it as DWORD-32
- Set the value of the item to `1`
- Reboot.

Comment: I am away from that PC now so can't test sorry. But I am surprised why this would work because I don't have this registry on any other PC which can access each other via c$ without any problem... :-\

Comment: I wonder why it's not needed on any other PC I have, but it works!